# Are virtual machine resources available to the host?

Tags: virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I know that when I dedicate HD space to the VM that it can’t be accessed by the host OS, but what about RAM and CPU cores/threads? I always thought that if I dedicate 2 cores and 8 GB of RAM to a VM that these were “taken away” from the host machine, but I am hearing from people that if multiple VMs are running and one is not using the resources then those resources are available to other VMs. Is this true only for VMs on a hypervisor or if I install multiple VMs on a standard Linux host OS is the same thing true?

Comment: Depends on the virtual machine manager, some will completely reserve it, others will use resources as needed.

Comment: I use VMware Player and the allocated resources are only used when needed. With an allocation of e.g. 4GB of RAM to a Linux distro the actual use is less than 1GB. The same is btw true for the host system. It never uses all the RAM for running but maybe for caching which is 'available' RAM.

Comment: "RAM can be shared among VMs" is a different statement than "RAM can be shared between a VM and other host applications."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is related to the concept of oversubscription [1] (allocating more virtual/logical resources than are physically available) in virtualization.

In general, it is safe to oversubscribe on CPU, but not on memory. Typically hypervisors reserve memory ahead of time, which deprives the host of its use, reserving the RAM for the guest. However, CPU is easily and readily shared between VMs and the host/hypervisor. Oversubscription is one of the main benefits of virtualization.

Also of note, you can achieve a similar effect with storage by making use of thin provisioning [2]. With thin provisioning, the hypervisor only allocates as much disk as is currently used by the guest OS.

[1] https://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/21181-102-1-28328/vsphere-oversubscription-best-practices%5B1%5D.pdf

[2] http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/03/thin-provisioning-whats-the-scoop.html